# Сделать background для linearLayout

Tags: java, android

Есть `ListView`, у него есть параметр `listSelector`. Есть `item.XML`, для адаптера. В `item.xml` `linear layout, imageView, TextView`.

Мне надо сделать `background` для `linearLayout`, но так, чтобы при клике срабатывал `listSelector`, который, в свою очередь, закрасит `background item.xml` красным цветом, не трогая `ImageView` and `TextView`.

**Обновление**

Проблема  в том что, если я указываю `background` для `linearLayout` в `item.xml`, то `listSelector` не работает, то есть вроде нажимаешь, а цвет не меняется, и фокус не остается. А если багруанд убрать, то все норм... как быть-то с баграундом?

**Обновление 2**

Прочитал ссылку в итоге ничегго не получилось

Вот код http://pastebin.com/hJMC9UjM `list_selector` устанавливаю в `GridView`, вместо стандартного `GridView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f00fff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000fff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff1118"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

BACKGROUND LinearLayout для item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:type="linear"
                  android:startColor="#626262"
                  android:endColor="#515151"
                  android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

**Обновление**

Прочитал ссылку в итоге ничего не получилось.

Вот код:

http://pastebin.com/hJMC9UjM

Эффект такой:

http://snag.gy/lrIXM.jpg

Помогите, пожалуйста. Может, баграунд в listSelector указать? Но тогда иконки пропадут, наверно. ((( Не знаю, что делать...

Comment: В чем проблема то?

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут очень хорошо расписано, как работает selector у ListView и как его создавать:
http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/08/08/listview-tips-tricks-3-create-fancy-listviews/

Comment: Я английский не знаю.

Comment: @asdasdasd, GoogleTranslate - может вполне адекватно переводить полутехнические тексты (почти всегда). Уж смысл точно можно понять, да и писать программы на английском и одновременно не знать его, это высший дивизион. И вообще, вся адекватная справка по java на английском, срочно исправляйтесь.